# How to I set Text Colour to a Disabled Button in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

I created an Quiz app in Kivy, when a question is presented there are 4 options (4 toggle buttons). Selecting a toggle button selects an answer and your answer is stored so to calculate the results.

At the end of the quiz, there is an option to review the quiz. The same screen is used as during the test but this time the 4 toggle buttons are disabled. Here is where I am having difficult trying to recreate a feature in KivyMD that I had in Kivy... I have included the original KIVY code at the end of this post and the KivyMD version below.

During the review, each toggle button is disabled but the text color indicates the right or wrong answer. The correct answer text color is "Green", if the user selected a wrong answer this text color is "Red" and all other buttons are just left as default. If the user selected the correct answer there is just one "Green" text and all others are default.

In Kivy I achevied this by creating four properties:

Button_A_Text_Color = StringProperty()
Button_B_Text_Color = StringProperty()

then I created an attribute UpdateButtons() that when called would check if it was "Test Mode" or "Review Mode". If the test was in "Test Mode", these properties would be set to a default color but if it was in "Review Mode" the color would be set based on the correct answer and on the answer given by the user. The UpdateButtons() was called ever time the user went from one questions to another...

Now, I think my problem lies with KivyMD using themes and there is much more things happening in the background and so my UpdateButtons() is being over written but a kivy toggle button attribute!

I have spent all morning looking through the KivyMD modules and did find some attributes that I tried to modify when I created my MyToggleButton class but the best i could do was to get the text to "Green" or "Red" or whatever during the test mode, in the "Review Mode" the text color kept defaulting back. In default mode the buttons are all set to Disable so I am thinking that there is an  attribute  somewhere that sets the button text to a certain color when its disabled. But I couldn't find it!!

Any ideas how to do this????

Sorry about the long question but just wanted to give sufficient detail... Below is the code and KV file, I tried to peel out all the unnecessary code and just leave in enough to show what I am trying to do!!

Thanks

Eoin

PY code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty,ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from random import shuffle

from kivymd.uix.behaviors.toggle_behavior import MDToggleButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatButton

source = [
{"question":"Press 1","A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","answer":"A"},
{"question":"Press 2","A":"3","B":"2","C":"1","D":"4","answer":"B"},
{"question":"Press 3","A":"2","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","answer":"C"},
{"question":"Press 4","A":"1","B":"4","C":"2","D":"3","answer":"D"},
]
TestQuestions = {}

for dict in source:
    TestQuestions[dict["question"]] = ([dict["A"].title(),dict["B"].title(),dict["C"].title(),dict["D"].title() ],dict[dict["answer"]].title()  )

def CreateTest(test = TestQuestions):
    Test = {}
    for Number, Question in enumerate([x for x in test.keys()]):
        Test[Number+1] =  {
                      "Current Question" : Question,
                      "Correct Answer" : TestQuestions[Question][1],
                      "Chosen Answer" : "Blank",
                      "Multiple Chocies" : TestQuestions[Question][0]}
    return Test

class QuestionsScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class ResultScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class TestScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class MyToggleButton(MDRoundFlatButton, MDToggleButton):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_down = MDApp.get_running_app().theme_cls.primary_dark

class QuizTestApp(MDApp):

    Status = BooleanProperty(False)
    TestComplete = BooleanProperty(False)

    Test = ObjectProperty()

    PassMark = 70
    TestCurrentQuestion = StringProperty()

    CurrentQuestionText = StringProperty("1")
    TotalQuestionsText = StringProperty("1")
    ChosenAnswerText = StringProperty()
    CurrentQuestion = 1
    TotalQuestions = NumericProperty(1)

    AnswerButtonA = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonB = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonC = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonD = StringProperty()

    AnswerButtonA_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonB_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonC_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonD_state = StringProperty("normal")

    Score = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Status = False
        self.CorrectAnswer = ""
        self.TestComplete = False
        self.CurrentQuestion = 1
        self.Test = CreateTest()
        self.TotalQuestions = 4  
        self.TotalQuestionsText = str(self.TotalQuestions)        
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()

    def UpdateChosenAnswer(self, button):
        self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] = button.text
        self.ChosenAnswerText = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"]
        self.DisableSubmitButton()

    def NextQuestion(self):
        self.CurrentQuestion +=1        
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()
                     
    def PreviousQuestion(self):
        self.CurrentQuestion -=1                
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()

    def StartTest(self, number):
        self.Status = False
        self.CorrectAnswer = ""
        self.TestComplete = False
        self.CurrentQuestion = 1
        self.Test = CreateTest(int(number), occuarnces = self.Stats["Questions Breakdown"])
        self.TotalQuestions = int(number)  
        self.TotalQuestionsText = str(self.TotalQuestions)        
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()

    def UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons(self):
        self.CurrentQuestionText = str(self.CurrentQuestion)
        self.TestCurrentQuestion = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Current Question"]
        self.AnswerButtonA, self.AnswerButtonB, self.AnswerButtonC, self.AnswerButtonD = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Multiple Chocies"]
        self.ChosenAnswerText = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"]
        self.HighLightButtonIfAnswered()
       
    def HighLightButtonIfAnswered(self):
        self.AnswerButtonA_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonB_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonC_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonD_state = "normal"

        def func(button_text):
            if self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] ==  button_text:
                return "down"
            elif self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] == "Blank":
                return "normal"
            else:  
                return "normal"            
        self.AnswerButtonA_state = func(self.AnswerButtonA)
        self.AnswerButtonB_state = func(self.AnswerButtonB)
        self.AnswerButtonC_state = func(self.AnswerButtonC)
        self.AnswerButtonD_state = func(self.AnswerButtonD)


    def SubmitTest(self):
        if self.Status == False:
            self.Score = self.CalculateScoreAndUpdateTestQuestionsBreakdown()

    def DisableSubmitButton(self):
        for Question in self.Test.keys():
            if self.Test[Question]["Chosen Answer"] == "Blank":
                self.TestComplete = False
                break
            else:
                self.TestComplete = True

    def CalculateScoreAndUpdateTestQuestionsBreakdown(self):
        score = 0
        for Question in self.Test.keys():
            if self.Test[Question]["Chosen Answer"]== self.Test[Question]["Correct Answer"]:
                score+=1
        return score
       
    def StartReview(self):
        self.TestComplete = True
        self.Status = True
        self.CurrentQuestion = 1
        self.CurrentQuestionText = str(self.CurrentQuestion)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        sm = MDScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))
        return sm
   
QuizTestApp().run()
```

KV file...

```
<MDLabel>:
    halign: "center"
    theme_text_color: "Secondary"
    font_style: "Body1"


<ResultScreen>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "20px"
        spacing: "20px"


        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            MDLabel:
                text: f"Your Score was {app.Score} out of {app.TotalQuestions}\n{round(app.Score/app.TotalQuestions*100)}%"
            MDLabel:
                text: "PASS" if app.Score/app.TotalQuestions*100 >= app.PassMark else "FAIL"
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            min_height: dp(10)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: "20px"
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: (1,1)
                text: "Review Questions" 
                on_press: app.StartReview();  root.manager.current = "test"; app.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()
                
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: (1,1)
                text: "exit"
                on_press:  app.get_running_app().stop()
   
<TestScreen>
    id: TestScreen
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDBoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)
            orientation: "horizontal"

        MDBoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers2
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers3
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)

        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: "20px"
            orientation: "vertical"


            MDLabel:
                text: app.TestCurrentQuestion
                text_size: self.width, None
                halign: "center"

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: "20px"
            spacing: "20px"
            MDBoxLayout:

                orientation: "horizontal"
                MyToggleButton:
                    id: AnswerButtonA
                    group: 1
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    #text_color: app.AnswerButtonA_color
                    text: app.AnswerButtonA
                    on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonA)
                    state: app.AnswerButtonA_state
                    disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False
                    size_hint: (0.5,1)

                MyToggleButton:
                    id: AnswerButtonB
                    group: 1
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    #text_color: app.AnswerButtonB_color
                    text: app.AnswerButtonB
                    on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonB)
                    state: app.AnswerButtonB_state
                    disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False
                    size_hint: (0.5,1)
            
            MDBoxLayout:

                orientation: "horizontal"
                MyToggleButton:
                    id: AnswerButtonC
                    group: 1
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    #text_color: app.AnswerButtonC_color
                    text: app.AnswerButtonC
                    on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonC)
                    state: app.AnswerButtonC_state
                    disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False
                    size_hint: (0.5,1)


                MyToggleButton:
                    id: AnswerButtonD
                    group: 1
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    #text_color: app.AnswerButtonD_color
                    text: app.AnswerButtonD
                    on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonD)
                    state: app.AnswerButtonD_state
                    disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False
                    size_hint: (0.5,1)

        MDBoxLayout:

            size_hint: (1,None)
            min_height: dp(10)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: "20px"
            spacing: "20px"

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: "Previous"
                size_hint: (0.3,1)                
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; app.PreviousQuestion()
                disabled: True if app.CurrentQuestionText == "1" else False

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: " Close Review" if app.Status else "Answer All Questions" if app.TestComplete==False else "Submit"
                #text_size: (50, None) if app.Status else (75, None) if app.TestComplete==False else (50, None)
                size_hint: (0.4,1)
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; 
                on_release: app.SubmitTest();  root.manager.current = "result"
                disabled: True if app.Status==False and app.TestComplete==False else False 

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: "Next"                
                size_hint: (0.3,1)
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; app.NextQuestion()            
                disabled: True if str(app.CurrentQuestionText)  == str(app.TotalQuestions) else False
```

Here is the original KIVY code that acheived the result. In the review page the button text color changes as per the answers...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty,ObjectProperty, NumericProperty 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

source = [
{"question":"Press 1","A":"1","B":"2","C":"3","D":"4","answer":"A"},
{"question":"Press 2","A":"3","B":"2","C":"1","D":"4","answer":"B"},
{"question":"Press 3","A":"2","B":"1","C":"3","D":"4","answer":"C"},
{"question":"Press 4","A":"1","B":"4","C":"2","D":"3","answer":"B"},
]
TestQuestions = {}

for dict in source:
    TestQuestions[dict["question"]] = ([dict["A"].title(),dict["B"].title(),dict["C"].title(),dict["D"].title() ],dict[dict["answer"]].title()  )

def CreateTest(test = TestQuestions):
    Test = {}
    for Number, Question in enumerate([x for x in test.keys()]):
        Test[Number+1] =  {
                      "Current Question" : Question,
                      "Correct Answer" : TestQuestions[Question][1],
                      "Chosen Answer" : "Blank",
                      "Multiple Chocies" : TestQuestions[Question][0]}
    return Test

class QuestionsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ResultScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestScreen(Screen):
    pass

class QuizTestApp(App):

    Status = BooleanProperty(False)
    TestComplete = BooleanProperty(False)

    Test = ObjectProperty()

    PassMark = 70
    TestCurrentQuestion = StringProperty()

    CurrentQuestionText = StringProperty("1")
    TotalQuestionsText = StringProperty("1")
    ChosenAnswerText = StringProperty()
    CurrentQuestion = 1
    TotalQuestions = NumericProperty(1)

    AnswerButtonA = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonB = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonC = StringProperty()
    AnswerButtonD = StringProperty()

    AnswerButtonA_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonB_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonC_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonD_state = StringProperty("normal")
    AnswerButtonA_color = ObjectProperty([1,1,1,1])
    AnswerButtonB_color = ObjectProperty([1,1,1,1])
    AnswerButtonC_color = ObjectProperty([1,1,1,1])
    AnswerButtonD_color = ObjectProperty([1,1,1,1])

    Score = NumericProperty()

    CurrentQuestionWidgetList = []

    StatsTestsCompleted = NumericProperty()
    StatsTestsPassed = NumericProperty()
    StatsQuestionsAnswered = NumericProperty()
    StatsCorrectAnswers = NumericProperty()
    StatsAverageResult = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Status = False
        self.CorrectAnswer = ""
        self.TestComplete = False
        self.CurrentQuestion = 1
        self.Test = CreateTest()
        self.TotalQuestions = 4
        self.TotalQuestionsText = str(self.TotalQuestions)        
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()

    def UpdateChosenAnswer(self, button):
        self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] = button.text
        self.ChosenAnswerText = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"]
        self.DisableSubmitButton()


    def NextQuestion(self):
        self.CurrentQuestion +=1        
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()
                      
    def PreviousQuestion(self):
        self.CurrentQuestion -=1                
        self.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()

    def UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons(self):
        self.CurrentQuestionText = str(self.CurrentQuestion)
        self.TestCurrentQuestion = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Current Question"]
        self.AnswerButtonA, self.AnswerButtonB, self.AnswerButtonC, self.AnswerButtonD = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Multiple Chocies"]
        self.ChosenAnswerText = self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"]
        self.HighLightButtonIfAnswered()
        
    def HighLightButtonIfAnswered(self):
        self.AnswerButtonA_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonB_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonC_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonD_state = "normal"
        self.AnswerButtonA_color = [1,1,1,1]
        self.AnswerButtonB_color = [1,1,1,1]
        self.AnswerButtonC_color = [1,1,1,1]
        self.AnswerButtonD_color = [1,1,1,1]

        def func(button_text):
            if self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] ==  button_text:
                return "down"
            elif self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] == "Blank":
                return "normal"
            else:   
                return "normal"             
        self.AnswerButtonA_state = func(self.AnswerButtonA)
        self.AnswerButtonB_state = func(self.AnswerButtonB)
        self.AnswerButtonC_state = func(self.AnswerButtonC)
        self.AnswerButtonD_state = func(self.AnswerButtonD)
        
        if self.Status == True: #Review mode
            def color_func(button_text):
                
                if self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] ==  button_text:
                    if self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Chosen Answer"] == self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Correct Answer"]:
                        return [0,1,0,1] #Green
                    else:   
                        return [1,0,0,1] #Red
                elif self.Test[self.CurrentQuestion]["Correct Answer"] == button_text:
                    return [0,1,0,1] #Green
                else:
                    return [1,1,1,0.5]        
            self.AnswerButtonA_color = color_func(self.AnswerButtonA)
            self.AnswerButtonB_color = color_func(self.AnswerButtonB)
            self.AnswerButtonC_color = color_func(self.AnswerButtonC)
            self.AnswerButtonD_color = color_func(self.AnswerButtonD)


    def SubmitTest(self):
        if self.Status == False:
            self.Score = self.CalculateScoreAndUpdateTestQuestionsBreakdown()

    def DisableSubmitButton(self):
        for Question in self.Test.keys():
            if self.Test[Question]["Chosen Answer"] == "Blank":
                self.TestComplete = False
                break
            else:
                self.TestComplete = True

    def CalculateScoreAndUpdateTestQuestionsBreakdown(self):
        score = 0
        for Question in self.Test.keys():
            if self.Test[Question]["Chosen Answer"]== self.Test[Question]["Correct Answer"]:
                score+=1
        return score
        
    def StartReview(self):
        self.TestComplete = True
        self.Status = True
        self.CurrentQuestion = 1
        self.CurrentQuestionText = str(self.CurrentQuestion)


    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))


        return sm
    
QuizTestApp().run()
```

KV

```
<Label>:
    text_size: self.width, None
    halign: "center"
    
<ResultScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "20px"
        spacing: "20px"


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: f"Your Score was {app.Score} out of {app.TotalQuestions}\n{round(app.Score/app.TotalQuestions*100)}%"
            Label:
                text: "PASS" if app.Score/app.TotalQuestions*100 >= app.PassMark else "FAIL"
        
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1,None)
            min_height: dp(10)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: "20px"
            Button:
                text: "Review Questions" 
                on_press: app.StartReview(); root.manager.current = "test"; app.UpdateQuestionAndAnswerButtons()
                
            Button:
                text: "exit"
                on_press:  app.get_running_app().stop()

<TestScreen>
    id: TestScreen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)
            orientation: "horizontal"

        BoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers2
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)
        
        BoxLayout:
            id: TopNumbers3
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)



        BoxLayout:
            padding: "20px"
            orientation: "vertical"


            Label:
                text: app.TestCurrentQuestion
                text_size: self.width, None
                halign: "center"


        GridLayout:
            padding: "20px"
            spacing: "20px"
            cols: 2
            rows: 2
            
            ToggleButton:
                id: AnswerButtonA
                group: 1
                color: app.AnswerButtonA_color
                text: app.AnswerButtonA
                on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonA)
                state: app.AnswerButtonA_state
                disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False

            ToggleButton:
                id: AnswerButtonB
                group: 1
                color: app.AnswerButtonB_color
                text: app.AnswerButtonB
                on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonB)
                state: app.AnswerButtonB_state
                disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False

            ToggleButton:
                id: AnswerButtonC
                group: 1
                color: app.AnswerButtonC_color
                text: app.AnswerButtonC
                on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonC)
                state: app.AnswerButtonC_state
                disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False

            ToggleButton:
                id: AnswerButtonD
                group: 1
                color: app.AnswerButtonD_color
                text: app.AnswerButtonD
                on_press: app.UpdateChosenAnswer(AnswerButtonD)
                state: app.AnswerButtonD_state
                disabled: True if self.text == "" or app.Status else False
                    
        BoxLayout:

            size_hint: (1,None)
            min_height: dp(10)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: "20px"
            spacing: "20px"

            Button:
                text: "Previous"
                size_hint: (0.3,1)                
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; app.PreviousQuestion()
                disabled: True if app.CurrentQuestionText == "1" else False

            Button:
                text: " Close Review" if app.Status else "Answer All Questions" if app.TestComplete==False else "Submit"
                #text_size: (50, None) if app.Status else (75, None) if app.TestComplete==False else (50, None)
                size_hint: (0.4,1)
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; 
                on_release: app.SubmitTest(); root.manager.current = "result"
                disabled: True if app.Status==False and app.TestComplete==False else False 

            Button:
                text: "Next"                
                size_hint: (0.3,1)
                on_press: AnswerButtonA.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonB.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonC.state = "normal"; AnswerButtonD.state = "normal"; app.NextQuestion()            
                disabled: True if str(app.CurrentQuestionText)  == str(app.TotalQuestions) else False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "MDFlatButton"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        disabled: True
        disabled_color: "red"
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

It works since the KivyMD library version 1.0.0.

[image]